# Verify installed app with UDID or IMEI

Tags: iphone, safari

I am running web app and trying to verify user's installed app with URL scheme.

- iPhone Web App
- Know user's UDID and IMEI
- Know specific app's URL scheme.

I have tried a lot of scripts but it doesn't really help me to verify installed app.

Checking time delay and transfer to App Store by Javascript doesn't verify whether its installed or not.

Our hypothesis are these.

- Get return result by checking Safari cookie with Custom URL scheme. (ex. twitter:// )
- Send a UDID parameter to iTunes Store to find its installation.

Some people might say it is impossible, but I believe, as a programmer, there should be a way to solve this problem.

Thank you.